# Formula works in cells, but not in Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have written the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(OFFSET(E5,0,0,1,(COLUMN($K5)-COLUMN(E5)+1)))=0,FALSE,TRUE)
```

e5 - beginning of range, k5 - end of range

It basically colors all cells in the given range (row) until it finds the last non-empty cell.

At least it was supposed to. The problem is - it works as a cell formula, but fails completely when applied as conditional formatting. The formula stays the same.

[Example -Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyuUQ.png)

Comment: Unrelated, but a formula in the form of `=IF(condition, FALSE, TRUE)` can be rewritten as `=NOT(condition)`.

Comment: Yes, the previous version looked like that, but in this way it's a little bit more readable. For me at least...

Comment: @Albert: it is actually not more readable. It is more confusing, and it is slower to calculate. You should use something like: `=COUNTA(...)<>0` or even: `=0<>COUNTA(...)`

Comment: @Albert: the image in the provided screenshot does not show the column names and the row numbers. That would be helpful.

Comment: @Albert: `until it finds the last non-empty cell` - is it in the true / false line, or in the colored line?

Comment: @virolino Formula is applied to either of the visible(colored) rows. No need widen the picture

Comment: @virolino - look at the picture :)

Comment: @Albert: please, in the picture I have no idea which column is E or K, and I do not know which line is "5". If the information is not there, then it is useless to look at the picture.

Comment: Let me be clear - in the first row (red) a formula is applied only trough cond. formatting and it works erroneously. In the second row (green), cond. formatting takes the value (TRUE,FALSE) from the cell below, where the very same formula is written and it works fine this time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So there is a working solution to the issue. 
https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/cf44pu/formula_works_in_cells_but_not_in_conditional/

basically all it takes is changing the original formula to:
=COUNTA(OFFSET(E5,0,0,1,COLUMN($K5)-COLUMN(E5)+1))<>0
Can anyone explain why this version works?